# Pass Response to React Component with Socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets

I am currently developing a component in ReactJS that should be able to display some data coming from a call to a server but unable to get the data to display dynamically in the child component

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
    import Main from "./Main";
    import Response from "./response"
    const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:4001";
    
    function App() {
      const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);
   
      useEffect(() => {
        const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
        socket.on("tick", (data) => {
          setResponse(data);
        });
      }, []);
    
      console.log(response);
    
      return (
        <>
          <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            <h1>Tradair Coding Assignment</h1>
    
    
            <Main
             responseCurrency = {response.map(memb => <div>{memb.currencyPairName} 
         </div>)}
            />
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

```
  import React from 'react';
  import './Main.css';
     
     class Main extends React.Component {
       render() {
        return (
           <div className="container">
     
             <div className="placeholder">hello {this.props.responseCurrency[0]}</div>
             <div className="placeholder"></div>
             <div className="placeholder"></div>
           </div>
         );
       }
     }
     
     export default Main;
```

this is my dummy data:

```
const arr1 = [{currencyPairName: "USD / ILS",prices: {bid: 3.15, offer: 2.65}},
               {currencyPairName: "EUR / USD",prices: {bid: 3.15, offer: 2.65}},
               {currencyPairName: "EUR / USD",prices: {bid: 3.15, offer: 2.65}}]
```

I also get this Error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot add node "1" because a node with that id is
> already in the Store.
> extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:25113:41
> at bridge_Bridge.emit (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:23328:22)
> at chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:23488:12
> at listener (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/main.js:51486:39)

I am a beginner in ReactJS, so I'm lost at the moment.

Comment: The error is probably because you do not pass a `key` prop to each `div` created inside the map function

Comment: Another possibility is that in doing `{this.props.responseCurrency[0]}`, you are duplicating the element. Try using `{React.cloneElement(this.props.responseCurrency[0])}`, and see if it makes a difference

Comment: no luck.. in case of a missing key, React gives a different warning and it shouldn't stop the data from updating with each tick. the second option failed to compile and gave me this error: Error: React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed undefined

Comment: The error you get from `React.cloneElement` seems strange. May I recommend instead of sending the divs to `Main` that you just pass the currency array to `Main` and have main render the `divs` itself